# What does 私はお願いしたいんですけど mean in this context?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4WlniHylrU&t=143s

This is a part of a legendary speech made by the former president of Nintendo at SpaceWorld. From my understanding, he is talking about the upcoming 64DD peripheral and how the technology could be used in games like Dragon Quest VII. Such a shame that over 2 decades later and not one sentence has been translated of this epic video. Even one minute translated would be nice. I wish translators would not view languages as simply a means of making their wallets fatter but rather be more giving and help translate timeless videos like these that embody video game culture. What a disgrace that translators don't even give back to the fans by helping with even one fan translation, instead, they are too busy doing jobs for the highest bidders of the richest clients.

私はお願いしたいんですけど、堀井さんも非常に興味を持っていただいて、なんとかやりたい。

しかも、そんな長い期間じゃなくて、新しいタネや仕掛けを使って一年半ぐらいで。<(this last part was added by me from ear)

今までのドラクエファン(dragon quest fan)が驚くような新しいタネや仕掛けを持ったドラゴンクエストを書き込めるソフトとして出すことに対して非常に積極的でありました。

Google translate:

I would like to ask, but Mr. Horii is also very interested and wants to do something.

Moreover, it's not a long period of time, but a year and a half using new seeds and devices. (what are seeds?)

Until now, Dragon Quest fan was very active in creating software that can write dragon quests with amazing new seeds and devices.

Comment: and your question is ???

Comment: My question is... everything above! Where do I even begin? I can translate manuals and news articles, but even one sentence from the speech above has me stumped! I hope I don't seem rude, but I don't even really know where to start. I can't even begin to sort of make sense of one sentence since this speech is almost untranslatable. If someone hired me to translate the above, I would have to return it back blank since this is way to hard for me to even make any sense of. How I love Japanese, the only language I've seen which doesn't complement itself. 1 video can be harder than a whole manual.

Comment: sorry I got lost once opened question. my bad. 私はお願いしたいんですけど is something specific to Japanese only which also shows their culture and humbleness.  Basically he's using polite form of Japanese. I agree with what you said, Japanese gets strange sometimes.

Comment: Here are articles about the phrase (as used in business): https://tap-biz.jp/business/honorific/1042250

Comment: I am grateful for any responses that I receive and the fact that anyone has even taken the time to reply to my cumbersome questions something I am very grateful for. With this post I posted above, I hope to emphasize just how difficult japanese speech can actually be, seeing as though this is never shown in grammar books, probably to keep readers from running away from the language to begin with. I also aimed to point out just how incompetent google translate could be in certain situations, as shown above, since this machine translation makes absolutely no sense and sounds like a drunken hobo.

Comment: It's お願いしたんですけど, to begin with. i.e. "I asked him, then, Mr.Horii was interested in it too, and (it went like) we wanted to do it somehow ...."

Comment: @ user4092 thanks! Any replies or comments are welcome in my posts. BTW, I asked a similar question on reddit, so maybe those answers might interested anyone else who wants to find out more about this post.https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/comments/dt58x7/japaneseenglish_nintendo_president_yamauchi_gives/f6wabdv/?context=3

Answer (score 0):

I think Yamauchi-san said "私はお願いしたんですけど", that is, he asked Horii-san to make dragon quest for the upcoming 64DD.
I think "タネ" is a trick to attract someone playing the game.
I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Anybody can translate japanese text, but a video with just speech is truly a remarkable feat, at least for me it is.